# variable with and without Binding suffix in a view - what's the difference?

Tags: ember.js

In the Ember guides we can find the following example:

```
{{view Ember.Select viewName="select" contentBinding="App.peopleController" optionLabelPath="model.fullName" optionValuePath="model.id" prompt="Pick a person:" selectionBinding="App.selectedPersonController.person"}}
```

one of the variables passed in to the view is bound to the PeopleController but the rest like `optionValuePath` are also connected to other parts of the app.

I'm a bit confused as sometimes I don't know which one I should use. But all of them will be accessible inside the view.

Is `optionLabelPath` (no '-Binding') the one-way binding or it just passes in the value once and for all?

What's the difference?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use the view helper to create an instance of a view from handlebars, all (ok, [most](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_view)) of the name=value pairs are passed to the view's create method. So:

```
{{view Ember.Select viewName="select" contentBinding="App.peopleController" optionLabelPath="model.fullName" optionValuePath="model.id" prompt="Pick a person:" selectionBinding="App.selectedPersonController.person"}}
```

becomes

```
view = Ember.Select.create({
    contentBinding="App.peopleController"
    optionLabelPath="model.fullName"
    optionValuePath="model.id"
    prompt="Pick a person:"
    selectionBinding="App.selectedPersonController.person"
})
```

So two of the properties, `content` and `selection`, have been *bound* to other parts of the app thanks to Ember's "AUTOMATIC CREATION OF BINDINGS WITH /^*Binding/-NAMED PROPERTIES" feature - see [Ember Binding API docs](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Binding.html).

> Is optionLabelPath (no '-Binding') the one-way binding or it just passes in the value once and for all?

There is nothing special about the other 3 (no '-Binding') properties. Each has been set to a simple string. `Ember.Select` will loop over the content array (App.peopleController) and uses the `optionLabelPath` to lookup a label from each item in the array. And `optionValuePath` is used to lookup a value.

> What's the difference?

So anything ending in `Binding` is expecting path to some other object. Everything else is just passed as a string. Ember.Select happens to use the two `Path` properties in a special way, but it's just a naming convention.

Comment: Thank you very much, Mike! The example with create() helped me much! One more question, though. Every ArrayController has the `content` array that becomes the context for a given template. So in the example template I could write {{fullName}}. Is referencing `model.fullName` the only way to look it up in the `content` array?

Comment: Not sure I follow. An arrayController's `content` array is typically not the context for a template, the controller itself is. If you do something like `{{#each this}}{{fullName}}{{/each}}`, the block will be rendered for every element in the arrayController's `content` array. I can't think of any situation where you would use `model.fullname` to reference an element from the content property of an arrayController.